# how to show the data of an xml in a datatable using php

Tags: php, xml, parsing, datatable

Below is the xml I am getting from as response from REST webservice call in a php method

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<response>
    <products>
      <capacity>1</capacity>
      <id>ae123</id>
      <group>Per</group>
      <name>xxxx</name>
    </products>
    <records>1
    </records>
</response>
```

My php method which calls the webservice and getting the xml data is

```
function getAjaxProducts(){

    $path="my webservice url";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type:     application/json'));
    $retValue = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if($httpCode>400) {
            $retValue="<error><errorcode>".$httpCode."</errorcode></error>";
            echo $retValue;
    }

    curl_close($ch);
    echo $retValue;
 }
```

`$retValue` contains the xml file.

I am totally new to `php` and don't know as to how I can show the product details in a datatable from the xml. 
Any idea regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

[`simplexml_load_string()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) should do the trick

```
$retValue = '<response>
  <products>
      <capacity>1</capacity>
      <id>ae123</id>
      <group>Per</group>
      <name>xxxx</name>
  </products>
  <records>1
  </records>
</response>';


$xml = simplexml_load_string($retValue);
echo $xml->products->capacity . "<br>\n";
echo $xml->products->group . "<br>\n";
echo $xml->products->name . "<br>\n";
echo $xml->records . "<br>\n";
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/dLLN1T)

Comment: As you can see in my link it does work so you need to make sure you are getting the XML value to `simplexml_load_string()` properly. `var_dump($retValue)`  to make sure you're getting expected values.

Comment: @john....when i do "echo $retValue;" i get the xml file, but when i am doing "echo $xml" after simplexml_load_string($retValue), it is coming blank. I dont understand where the problem lies. Please help me